# Удалить None значения элементов словаря в Python

Tags: python, словари, for

Нужно удалить все элементы словаря, у которых значение None. Пытался так:

```
for item in dic:
    if dic[item] is None:
        del dic[item]
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/725717 здесь подробно пояснили как справиться с ошибкой

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dic = {k:v for k, v in dic.items() if v is not None}
```

Comment: Всё работает. Можете пояснить, как это устроено?

Comment: Это [словарное включение](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) генерирующее новый словарь на основе старого.

Comment: можно ещё фильтром

Comment: @eri можно, но Гвидо рекомендует всегда использовать включения вместо map и filter.

Comment: с включениями иногда такая хрень получается нечитаемая...